# "Operation not permitted" error while trying pip uninstall on Mac

Tags: python, macos-sierra

I am trying to uninstall a package installed on `MacOS Sierra` with `pip`.

```
pip uninstall -y altgraph
```

I've got an error:

> Error[('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-0Bm0Kc/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
>   ...

I tried run it with `sudo` but got the same error.

How can I fix it and uninstall the package ?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have the module installed in several locations - meaning that a single 'pip uninstall' command would not remove all of the package files.

Use a virtualenv:

```
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Add these to your ~/.bash_profile (open terminal, type 'open ~/.bash_profile'):

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Paste it in. Save. Then type 'source ~/.bash_profile' in the terminal window.

Finally, create a virtual environment:

```
python3 -m virtualenv NAMEOFVIRUTALENV
```

You will have a fresh slate to import/install modules from there.

Edit: One final step - immediately after typing the above, type the following in the terminal (make sure you're in the same directory that you executed the last command under):

```
source NAMEOFVIRTUALENV/bin/activate/
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will certainly do it. However I would like to remove the packages installed globally.

Comment: Notta prob. Yeah deleting all files globally when they're scattered around is a tough one..been there many times unfortunately. The only solution I could find was to find the files (including the hidden files) and delete them manually. It got to the point where I just backed up/restored my mac. I could have missed something though...

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks.